# How do you measure the accuracy of an inference hypothesis/procedure?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, inference, validation, accuracy

Take inference to mean reasoning/predicting the value of a hidden/laten variable $Z$ given some evidence/data $X$. For example, maybe you are trying to find out if your patient has Cancer (Z = 1 if he does, 0 if he doesn't) but you only have indirect ways of measuring it X. Say X could be the color of his skin, the ph of his blood, or whatever important features (or kernels of features) you might want to use.

One thing that I was curious is, if you normally do not have the label $Z$ in your data set, then how are you suppose to know how well your predictions for $Z$ might be once you create a hypothesis for predicting?

Another way to think about this question could be, if you have a data set $S_n$ (Set of size n) and you want to find hidden structure in it, how do you know that the hidden labels ($Z$) that you are learning are good just from the set $S_n$?

The only way I can think to asses this data set is, to somehow get "force" to get a "test set" that happens to have the hidden labels that are normally hidden and then predict see if the labels match with whatever cost function you want to you (say maybe counting number of correct predictions). However, if "forcing" to get $Z$ out of your data set is not possible, how are you suppose to get a feel of how good your hypothesis might be? Without labels, k-fold validation is not possible, right? Note that by force I mean is to obtain the unknown label $Z$ for some set that you plan to use as test set (though, "forcing" is probably not possible in many cases or tractable, since if it were tractable/doable, we probably would not be doing learning, we would just "force" the answer out of the data set every time we need to!)

---

I am both interested in a **"practical" answer**, what professional machine learners do in practice and a **theoretical answer**, i.e. an answer that relies more on mathematical techniques/proof on how to measure accuracy in this case or even, a proof of why maybe unless with further assumptions, it might be impossible to do anything.

Comment: Hello Charlie Parker, I am a little confused by your question, but in regression/classification contexts as the one in your cancer example, we always have observations $(Z_i, X_i)$ at our disposal, ie. observations of both the outcome and the inputs of observation each $i$.

Comment: hi @jubo, I guess another way of phrasing my question is, when we are trying to learn laten variables, how do we measure the accuracy of the way our hypothesis labels data points? A good example could be clustering, where we try to infer labels based on the the structure. How do we measure the accuracy of our clusters? (Or similarly if we applied the EM algorithm, how do we measure if the hypothesis we got from the EM is "good" [or generalized or some measure of goodness] if we are learning laten variables?)

Comment: The main problem I am confused about is,in the case of latent variables,how do we know our hypothesis is doing a good job? does my question make kind of sense now?Of course if it were a supervised problem were we had the labels whether they were continuous or discrete,my question wouldn't really make sense as its obvious how to calculate accuracy since we have the labels! Just come up with a measure of "closeness" to the actual labels and there you go, you have a metric to measure accuracy (or loss).It could be zero one loss, or squared error or whatever is appropriate(but you know the labels)

Answer (score 1):

//  Without labels, k-fold validation is not possible, right? //

Correct, you cannot measure accuracy.  The only thing you can do is manually analyse the output to see if it seems correct-ish, so you may take 1000 examples and manually label them yourself in the hope your human powers of classification are quite accurate.  Of course manual classification to build a test set is very very boring, so you might want to get in some interns! hehehe

Seriously though, some applications of machine learning work like this.  Outlier detection, fraud detection, etc, can often be done quite well by humans, but not at scale.  So companies use both machine learning and humans, when an algorithm tends to agree with the humans most of the time, they fade out use of the humans.

So if your problem is easy for humans to do at a small scale, like, say, "does this picture have an apple in it" you can generate a small test set to get an idea of accuracy.